# Custom Metadata depending on the language in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, seo

Is there a way to provide custom Metadata to users based on the keywords from the search engine?

In order to improve SEO on my website, I'm trying to set up custom Metadata for both languages supported on my website: English and Portuguese. More specifically, provide the Next.js 13 Metadata API with some logic to achieve it.

Here's the code so far from the `layout.tsx` file:

```
...
const englishMetadata = {
  title: {
    default: "brand",
    template: "%s | brand.xyz",
  },
  description:
    "Some description",
  openGraph: {
    title: "brand",
    description:
      "Some description",
    url: "brand.xyz",
    siteName: "brand",
    type: "website",
  },
  robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
      "max-video-preview": -1,
      "max-image-preview": "large",
      "max-snippet": -1,
    },
  },
  icons: {
    shortcut: "/favicon.png",
  },
  keywords:
    "events clothing, ...",
};

const portugueseMetadata = {
  title: {
    default: "Brand",
    template: "%s | brand.xyz",
  },
  description:
    "Alguma descrição",
  openGraph: {
    title: "brand",
    description:
      "Alguma descrição",
    url: "brand.xyz",
    siteName: "brand",
    type: "website",
  },
  robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: true,
      follow: true,
      "max-video-preview": -1,
      "max-image-preview": "large",
      "max-snippet": -1,
    },
  },
  icons: {
    shortcut: "/favicon.png",
  },
  keywords:
    "eventos, vestuário, ...",
};

// export const metadata: Metadata = ? portugueseMetadata : englishMetadata;
export const metadata: Metadata = {};
```

Comment: Hi Braz! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`generateMetadata`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#generatemetadata-function) function. In an internalization setup where the URL param for the lang is called `lang`, it would be something like this:

```
// app/[lang]/page.js 

const englishMetadata = {
  title: "Hello Enlish Man",
};
const portugueseMetadata = {
  title: "Hello Portuguese Man",
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  return params.lang === "en-US" ? englishMetadata : portugueseMetadata;
}

export default function Page() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` dynamic metadata like this:

```
export async function generateMetadata() {

    const {t} = await getTranslations(); // here use your way to get translation string

    return {
        title: t("appTitle"),
        description: t("appDescription")
    }
}
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata